# Can someone say how can I get to this network management window in my android device

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, android-device-manager, application-manager

My device is vivo 1718 android 8.1. I have found this Network Management window when I didn't turn on mobile data access for one app. That app pops up an alert to change the network access and when I press to change it, I am directed to this window:

[image]
<sup>network management window (click to enlarge)</sup>

But after that I can't find it anywhere in my settings.

Comment: I don't have your device, but do you have an "iManager" app? The Data Monitor in that might have it.

Comment: Xiaomi devices has a security app, in which you can set which applications should use data or wifi, under data usage. Vivo is also a custom android device, which also may have such app in its applications.

Answer (score 0):

As in @dewey's comment that is located inside iManager App 'Network management' section. Here is the path.

iManager -> Data Monitor -> Network Management